# Google App Engine as part of a load balanced service

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a set of servers that are currently using a single domain name with multiple DNS A records to round robin load balance. I have ported my service to run on the Google App Engine and I would like to add the google hosted service to the round robin list on the domain name. However GAE apps do not get assigned a static IP address. All I get from google is a domain name for the service.

The organization I work for requires that the service not be hosted by a single company to provide a sufficient level of fail over redundancy. I would like to host part of this service on GAE but I don't see any way to do it and still have it accessed by the same domain name as the rest of the servers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

Google App Engine uses CNAME records to "point" a domain to their GAE infrastructure. Due to the way how CNAME works, CNAME must be the only record for a FQDN.

One of the solutions is to use [DNSMadeEasy's ANAME service](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/aname-records/) which resolves the CNAME record into an A record. HTTP-level forwarding/balancing may also get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very much appreciated. I don't think the ANAME service really solves the problem as I think that would then make DNSMadeEasy the single point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a top level custom domain to App Engine, Google will give you a list of multicast IPs to use instead of the CNAME, as mostly you can't use a CNAME for the root DNS record.

Since they expect people to have to put them in as A records, I expect they won't change, although can't say if they are different per region.